Can I merge two tables into one?
I'm using Table to generate such a lattice
n = 3;
pts1 = Flatten[Table[{j - i, n - i + 1}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 2 i - 1}], 1];
pts2 = Flatten[Table[{i + j + n, i}, {i, -n, 0}, {j, -2 i - 2 n, 0}], 1];
Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Point@pts1, Point@pts2}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]

I feel like there should be a more concise way, maybe in this form:
pts = Flatten[Table[{f[i, j], g[i, j]}, {i, -n, n}, {j, -2 i - 2 n, 2 i - 1}], 1]
I don't know how to construct it, is it possible?

Observe the lower and the upper bound, and see that you can utilize Abs:
pts = With[{a = 3}, Catenate@Table[{i, j}, {i, -a, a}, {j, Abs[i] - a, a - Abs[i]}]]


This is just a one-liner:
n = 3;
pts = Cases[Tuples[Range[-n, n], 2], {a_, b_} /; Abs[a] + Abs[b] <= n];
Graphics[{PointSize@Large, Point@pts}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]

Alternatively, the condition can be formulated even more concisely as
pts = Select[Tuples[Range[-n, n], 2], Norm[#, 1] <= n &];


You may achive this using "Table"
n = 3;
d = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {j, -n, n}, {i, -n + Abs[j], n - Abs[j]}], 
   1];

Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[d]}, Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]



A variant that generates the coordinates by solving the inequality Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= n over Integers
pts = Block[{n = 3, x, y}, SolveValues[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= n, {x, y}, Integers]]; 
Graphics[Point@pts]



Graphics[
  {PointSize@Large, Point[Position[DiamondMatrix[3], 1] - Threaded[{4, 4}]]}, 
  Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]

DiamondMatrix gives you a matrix representation of the "shape" you want.
DiamondMatrix[3]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}} *)

The positions where 1 occur are the coordinates you want:
Position[DiamondMatrix[3], 1]
(* {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, 
    {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, 
    {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, 
    {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {7, 4}} *)

We can just wrap them in Point and display them:
Graphics[Point[Position[DiamondMatrix[3], 1]]]


If you want to show the axis and have it be centered, then you can shift all the points accordingly (thus the - Threaded[{4, 4}]). You could also just move the origin:
Graphics[
  {PointSize[Large], Point[Position[DiamondMatrix[3], 1]]}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {4, 4}, Ticks -> None]

